# WPF: programatically draw a Rectangle to an ImageSource instance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to C# and to WPF, and I could be looking at this completely wrong.  I have a JPEG byte array as a source.  I cannot change this.  I need to get the array, perform some calculations and draw rectangles in areas of the JPEG.  I then write it to an Image XAML control.

I get the JPEG and I can convert it into an `ImageSource` and display it to an `ImageControl`.  I can't find a way to get the drawing context from the `ImageSource`.  I use `ImageSourceConverter` to read in the JPEG array and this class returns an `ImageSource` instance, duh!.

```
ImageSource mImage = (ImageSource)mConverter.ConvertFrom(mImageBuffer);
```

`ImageSource` does not have a drawing context property.

What it seems like I need is a `DrawingImage`, it is derived from `ImageSource` and has a drawing context property.

How can I use a `DrawingImage` instead of the `ImageSource`.

I looked at the `ImageDrawing` class, it has an `ImageSource` property. This class doesn't have a drawing context.

I am currently looking into the Visual class, and help where to look would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Thanks @nefarious for pointing me in the right direction.  I ended with the following:

```
ImageSource mImage = (ImageSource)mConverter.ConvertFrom(mImageBuffer);

BitmapSource bImage = mImage as BitmapSource;

// Draw a Rectangle
DrawingVisual dVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext dc = dVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    dc.DrawImage(bImage, new Rect(0, 0, bImage.PixelWidth, bImage.PixelHeight));
    dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Green, null, new Rect(20, 20, 150, 100));
}
RenderTargetBitmap targetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(640,480,96,96, PixelFormats.Default);
targetBitmap.Render(dVisual);

WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(targetBitmap);
image.Source = wBitmap;
```

Comment: Funny that you're loading an ImageSource now, although you insisted on loading a WinForms Bitmap. Anyway, you may want to take a look at [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I don't remember wanting a WinForms Bitmap.  I have never used WinForms?

Comment: In your previous question, two days ago, where I was trying to tell you *not* to use the classes from the System.Drawing namespace, because it's WinForms, however without success. I had to edit the answer that you wrongly accepted.

Comment: The answer I accepted asked me to be sure I knew that I was using the wpf class instead of the WinForms class.  I was mixing them because I couldn't tell which was which.. I have always wanted wpf.

Comment: That's not true. Before my edit, it ended with "try using System.Drawing.Bitmap", then you accepted it. I was telling you that this is not what you typically do in WPF, and that it may potentially give bad advice to other newbies having the same problem.

Comment: I have to apologize for how that question went.  The answer I accepted had one part that was what I needed, it may have had other things I didn't need.  The part that was important to me was to be sure I knew the framework for the class I was using.  And in fact that was my problem, I was mixing WinForms and WPF.  I took from this what I needed to be consistent with the WPF class.  That's how I ended with the ImageSource.  Can we stop arguing about this?

Comment: This MSDN page has a XAML example of how to draw lines and such. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx and here's some super basic tutorial on just drawing a single line. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/line-in-wpf/ That should help get you started at least :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using Visuals, I don't know how efficient they are but it seems that you will be unable to copy the source into an ImageSource and draw directly into it.

Create a DrawingVisual and draw the ImageSource and the Rectangles into the drawing context of the drawing visual.

Then use [WriteableBitmap](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/555-drawing-bitmaps-drawingimage-and-drawingvisual-.html?start=1) to show it in the image;